# Govendor license command apparently skipping the vendor folder and only using Gopath

Tags: go, govendor

I've had some success with 'govendor license' in the past, but now, it seems to only be searching in GOPATH, rather than looking in the vendor folder first.

```
dibbj@USENDIBBJL4C MINGW64 ~/go/src/mlx-agent (master)
$ govendor license
Error: Failed to discover license for "github.com/StackExchange/wmi" open `C:\Users\dibbj\go\src\github.com\StackExchange\wmi: The system cannot find the path specified.`

dibbj@USENDIBBJL4C MINGW64 ~/go/src/mlx-agent (master)
$ ls vendor/github.com/StackExchange/wmi
LICENSE  README.md  swbemservices.go  wmi.go

GOPATH=C:\Users\dibbj\go
```

I'm getting the same behavior on both Ubuntu and Win10.  Other govendor commands seem to work and in fact show the correct path

```
 $ govendor list -p
 vu C:\Users\dibbj\go\src\mlx-agent\vendor\github.com\StackExchange\wmi                  
 vu C:\Users\dibbj\go\src\mlx-agent\vendor\github.com\shirou\gopsutil\internal\common    
 vu C:\Users\dibbj\go\src\mlx-agent\vendor\github.com\shirou\gopsutil\process            
 vu C:\Users\dibbj\go\src\mlx-agent\vendor\golang.org\x\sys\unix 

$ govendor -version
v1.0.9

$ go version
go version go1.10.3 windows/amd64
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Any suggestions?

Comment: So, I think it's a bug with govendor license where if the first package is tagged with 'u' it doesn't work.  When I added the +local flag, or +external flag, it worked.  On the other hand, it only printed a license for 3 of 20 or 30 packages but at least it found one.